# Map SNP IDs to genome coordinates

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, genetics, genome

I have several [SNP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-nucleotide_polymorphism) IDs (i.e., rs16828074, rs17232800, etc...), I want to their coordinates in a Hg19 genome from [UCSC genome website](http://genome-euro.ucsc.edu/).

I would prefer using `R` to accomplish this goal.  How to do that?

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you working with FASTA files?  Can't you simply run a multiple sequence alignment?

Comment: I am not working with FASTA files but I can though.  I believe there are many ways to accomplish this but I am asking the easiest way to do it.  Thanks.

Comment: Any Python3 options for this? I found cruzdb but that seems to work only with Python2.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a solution using the Bioconductor package `biomaRt`. It is a slightly corrected and reformatted version of the previously posted code.

```
library(biomaRt) # biomaRt_2.30.0

snp_mart = useMart("ENSEMBL_MART_SNP", dataset="hsapiens_snp")

snp_ids = c("rs16828074", "rs17232800")
snp_attributes = c("refsnp_id", "chr_name", "chrom_start")

snp_locations = getBM(attributes=snp_attributes, filters="snp_filter", 
                      values=snp_ids, mart=snp_mart)

snp_locations
#    refsnp_id chr_name chrom_start
# 1 rs16828074        2   232318754
# 2 rs17232800       18    66292259
```

Users are encouraged to read the comprehensive `biomaRt` [vignette](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.pdf) and experiment with the following `biomaRt` functions:

```
listFilters(snp_mart)
listAttributes(snp_mart)
attributePages(snp_mart)
listDatasets(snp_mart)
listMarts()
```

Comment: May I ask filters="snp_filter" mean?  Thanks.

Comment: From page 7 of the vignette: "Filters define a restriction on the query. For example you want to restrict the output to all genes located on the human X chromosome then the filter 'chromosome_name' can be used with value 'X'". With no filter, you would get all the snps in the chosen database. Try the command `listFilters(snp_mart)` to see what filters are possible.

Comment: I've noticed this takes a very very long time if you have a large number of SNPs, e.g. 200,000 ish (say with an Affymetrix 6.0 SNP array and wish positions for all of the SNPS). I wonder if anyone knows a faster way to do this.

Comment: @JimBo, I have also noticed very slow response from biomaRt databases, even when the output is as few as 2000 lines. It may be worth posting on the bioconductor mailing list (http://www.bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/).

Answer (score 4):

Via Perl you will find it quite easy to build code to query for SNPs.

There is a web browser GUI tool ([**HERE**](http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/ad23fb5685e6aecb59ab12ce73c89731)) for building perl scripts based on which database and dataset you wish to query using Biomart library.

**Instructions**

1. Go to http://www.ensembl.org/biomart/martview/ad23fb5685e6aecb59ab12ce73c89731 (for supported Metazoans), or http://biomart.vectorbase.org/biomart/martview/6e274bc00b3c68a131a6947d02039ade (for up to date Vectors of Malaria, e.g. *[A. gambiae](https://www.vectorbase.org/organisms/anopheles-gambiae)*)
2. Select the database and dataset: [image]
3. Click on the "perl" button to generate perl code for the Biomart API querying, and copy-paste the code into your perl editor - run it with the SNP rsNumbers of your choice.

> ```
> # An example script demonstrating the use of BioMart API.
> use strict;
> use BioMart::Initializer;
> use BioMart::Query;
> use BioMart::QueryRunner;
>
> my $confFile = "PATH TO YOUR REGISTRY FILE UNDER biomart-perl/conf/."
> my $action='cached';
> my $initializer = BioMart::Initializer->new('registryFile'=>$confFile,'action'=>$action);
> my $registry = $initializer->getRegistry;
>
> my $query = BioMart::Query->new('registry'=>$registry,'virtualSchemaName'=>'default');
>     $query->setDataset("hsapiens_snp");
>     $query->addAttribute("refsnp_id");
>     $query->addAttribute("refsnp_source");
>     $query->addAttribute("chr_name");
>     $query->addAttribute("chrom_start");
>     $query->formatter("TSV");
>
> my $query_runner = BioMart::QueryRunner->new();
>
> ############################## GET RESULTS ##########################
> $query_runner->execute($query);
> $query_runner->printHeader();
> $query_runner->printResults();
> $query_runner->printFooter();
> #####################################################################
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using bioconductor's **biomaRt** R package.

This provides an easy way to send queries to [BioMart](http://www.biomart.org/) which fetches information about SNPs given an rsNumber (i.e. [rsid](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/docs/rs_attributes.html#refsnp)).

E.g. to import SNP data for **rs16828074** (an rsNumber you listed in the post), use this:

***Code:***

```
library(biomaRt)

snp.id <- 'rs16828074'   # an SNP rsNumber like you listed in the post

snp.db <- useMart("snp", dataset="hsapiens_snp")  # select your SNP database

# The SNP data file imported from the HUMAN database:
nt.biomart <- getBM(c("refsnp_id","allele","chr_name","chrom_start",                   
                      "chrom_strand","associated_gene",
                      "ensembl_gene_stable_id"),
                      filters="refsnp",
                      values=snp.id,
                      mart=snp.db)
```

Let me know how you get on with this (via comments) since I assume some basic coding and package importing ability in my answer here.

***Aknowledgement/s:***

goes to [Jorge Amigo](https://www.biostars.org/u/375/) (for his [post](http://www.biostars.org/p/1332/) in Biostars)

Comment: I am getting the following error when I ran your code.  Error in getBM(c("refsnp_id", "allele", "chr_name", "chrom_start", "chrom_strand",  : 
  Invalid filters(s): refsnp 
Please use the function 'listFilters' to get valid filter names

Comment: look at the post by @bdemarest, he seemed to have got there before me ^^, I will post another answer based on perl programming language, this is the most recommended language for SNP querying I believe

Comment: You meant to say thanks to "Jorge Amigo" not "Zach Stednick". And how is your post different from accepted answer by "bdemarest" ?

Comment: @zx8754 you are correct, on both counts, my apologies. I have edited correct aknowledgement. Why did I have the same answer to "bdemarest"? Originally I didn't realise the syntax was in R, only now do I realise this. Please flag my post as duplicate

Comment: Thanks, let it stay, I like the link to biostars :)