# Identify SNP from genetic position

Tags: r, genetics, gwas

I am looking for a way to obtain SNP names from their coordinates (Chromosome:BP) - very much the reverse of the question answered here:

([Map SNP IDs to genome coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20251612/map-snp-ids-to-genome-coordinates))

Is this possible in R - and if so, how?

Comment: This really isn't a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. You seem to really need to know about sources for specific genomic datasets. This may be a better fit for a site like [bioinformatics.se] or https://www.biostars.org/. Just asking for package recommendations without any test data for verification is considered off-topic.

Comment: Reason I posted here is the other question which asked for a reverse query. I don't think it is just a package.

Comment: That question was posted back in 2013. These newer sites didn't exist then and what's considered on/off topic has changed. It all comes down to what reference data you want to use. Likely you'll want to use some version of the dbSNP database but not that different versions change variant positions over time. Plus you need to know exactly what reference genome was used to generate your chr/position information as variants are located at different positions in different builds. One you have the correct reference data, then you can just merge that to your own data.

Comment: Thank you - I will relocate. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: Question has been moved to (https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/20137/identify-snp-from-genetic-position) as suggested.